# How can my site be able for mobile device

Tags: html, css

I wanna to make my logo(KP advisory) and text responsive when resize the browser in full width, but unfortunately just mi background image resize. Maybe it's not hard to do but i don't know where is the problem. Also need to be able for mobile devices. Please help.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="banner">
                <img src="logo1.png" class="logo" width="650px" height="215px">
                    <h4 class="heading mt-100">KP business & financial<br>advisory services d.o.o.
                Beograd<br><br>Resavska 23,<br>1100 Beograd, Srbija<br><br>
                <a href="mailto:office@kp-advisory.com " class="link">office@kp-advisory.com</a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.link {
    color:white;
}

html {
    background: fixed;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('pozadina.png') no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.mt-100 {
    margin-top: 80p;
    font-size: 22px;
    align-content: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    height: 100%;

}
.banner {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: -190px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 330px;
  background-size: cover;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **media queries**, in css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

EDIT:
In your situation (example):

```css
.banner {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .banner {
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

If your window browser has a maximum 600px - you see red font and yellow background.

Comment: Can you share mi some optional code for my situation? Because i try with media queries but probably don't know what is the problem. Thank you a lot for answer :)

Comment: Oh my friend, you definitely save myself. Thank you a lot once again. Today i learned that media queries are so much needed to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean but here you have the basis to do a responsive website.

```css
.link {
  color: white;
}

body {
  background: #4d4d4d;
  margin: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.mt-100 {
  font-size: 22px;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  transition: 0.24s;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60%;
  transition: 0.24s;
}

.logo {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transition: 0.24s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 765px) {
  .banner {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .logo {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }

  .mt-100 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="banner">
                <img src="logo1.png" class="logo" width="650px" height="215px">
                    <h4 class="heading mt-100">KP business & financial<br>advisory services d.o.o.
                Beograd<br><br>Resavska 23,<br>1100 Beograd, Srbija<br><br>
                <a href="mailto:office@kp-advisory.com " class="link">office@kp-advisory.com</a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot bro! All the best! :)